# How do I add a authorization rule to IIS that allows Paypal IPN to send notifications back to the listener?

Tags: iis, paypal

When I have the authorization rule in IIS under-.net authorization rules-set to deny anonymous users both the IPN simulator and the IPN I have set in my sandbox fail. When I remove the rule it works fine. Is there a way I can create a rule that will allow incoming notifications from paypal to my IIS server?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give every one an update- I have resolved this issue partially by creating two rules-in the web.config file- one that denies read access to the website for anonymous users- and another which allows them to post messages to the listener-

```
 <authorization> <!--change authorization here-->
  <deny users="?" verbs="GET" />
  <allow users="?" verbs="POST" />
  </authorization>
```

Ideally I would like to create a rule that only allows POSTs from a ip address domain reserved explicitly by Paypal. If anyone has any ideas on how to go about doing this- I would greatly appreciate some input.